# Android data binding MockK: Missing calls inside every { } block

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-databinding, mockk

I am using MockK for unit tests. When I try to mock data binding class generated for my layout I'm getting strange error. I want to mock one of the views inside the layout the data binding class wraps using

> `every { binding.someView } returns mockedView`

but I'm getting

> io.mockk.MockKException: Missing calls inside every { ... } block.

When I try the same with binding variable defined in `<data>` block of the layout everything works as expected. But views don't.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any luck?

Comment: @Montwell no, mate, sorry. It seems it's not possible.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been a while since the question was posted, but I seem to have found a way to do this.

```
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import com.example.R
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.MockK
import io.mockk.junit5.MockKExtension
import io.mockk.unmockkAll
import io.mockk.verify
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith

@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
internal class BindingMockkExample {

    private lateinit var binding: MyBinding

    @MockK(relaxed = true)
    private lateinit var rootView: ConstraintLayout

    @MockK(relaxed = true)
    private lateinit var textView: TextView

    @MockK(relaxed = true)
    private lateinit var imageView: AppCompatImageView

    @BeforeEach
    fun beforeEach() {
        every { rootView.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(R.id.my_image_view) } returns imageView
        every { rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_text_view) } returns textView
        binding = MyBinding.bind(rootView)
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun afterEach() {
        unmockkAll()
    }

    @Test
    fun `GIVEN something WHEN something happens THEN imageView becomes invisible`() {
        // do something that should make image invisible
        
        verify { imageView.isVisible = false }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.